# Why does visual studio gives me error when I want to run the GAMS code via C#?

Tags: c#, gams-math

I want to run my GAMS code via c# by GAMS API. when I start Visual studio,I recieve this error in

```
GAMSWorkspace ws = new GAMSWorkspace();
```

> error: "Expected GAMS system to be 32 bit but found 64 bit instead.
>   System directory: C:\GAMS\win64\25.1"

GAMS and windows are both 64 bit.

Can anybody help me to solve it?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: my windows and GAMS both are 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://forum.gamsworld.org/viewtopic.php?t=7828 Lutz says:

> Normally this error only occurs if you built your application as a
>   32bit version explicitly. Could you please check if you still get the
>   error if you select x64 as platform for your program in the
>   configuration manager of Visual Studio?

Comment: I change platform In configuration manager, but it still gives this error.

Comment: Is GAMS.net4.dll for both 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: How is platform target set on project build properties?

Comment: Yep. You could try reinstall 64bit version. https://www.gams.com/download/

Comment: I create new project and change platform to x64 and it works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Lutz I didn't knew how to proper do it. Fix it